# Sitecore Webform for Marketers 8.1 Send Email Message doesn't send email

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, web-forms-for-marketers

WFFM Ver 8.1 rev 151008

Version 8 works fine.

No errors in log file and no any error generated.

truetrue

parameters included.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting up a local development SMTP server and seeing if the message makes it to that?

Comment: Yes i did with smtp4dev. didn't work, but sitecore 8 solution work fine. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in that version with the SendEmail. A fix is available from Sitecore Support as this bug is already known. You can ask them with the reference number 78070.

Or upgrade.. it has been fixed in the next versions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test it out and let you know.

Comment: I have used the version after(Update-1)

Comment: If you apply this fix in 8.1 and later upgrade to 8.1.2, make sure to remove the fix again, as it will break the SendEmail function